# Why would half of Azure worker instances not start and hit a SecurityException?

Tags: .net, azure, cloud

I'm trying to increase the number of instances deployed for a cloud service. When I do the deploy 5 out of the 10 instances deploy correctly.  The other half never start and get a  "System.Security.SecurityException".

Very frustrating since I would think the package deployed is the same to all 10 instances.  Why would only half fail?  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?  Thanks!

**What I've tried so far**

- Deleted and created new cloud service
- Toggle deploy update option on and off

[image]

**Full stack of exception**

Application: WaWorkerHost.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Security.SecurityException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.b__0()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a Firewall setting on the SQL Server.  The error was trying to write out to the registry, which was causing the security exception.

Comment: How were you able to find the cause?

Comment: @ShaneCourtrille  I think we RDPed into the server and looked at the event logs.